# How to get access into dictionary created in global asax file?

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-web-api

In global.asax file in my web api project I'am creting a Dictionary just before Application_Start. This Dictionary will store tokens and expiring date. But honestly.. I don't know how to access this dictionary.

Could you tell me how can I get access to this dictionary around all classes?

Comment: store it in Application object or simply make it static.

Comment: I'am trying now with Application object.

Comment: Your approach for something like this is really not going to work (or scale). I suggest you look at a distributed storage mechanism like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: @James your assuming that his project will need to scale. His approach might be fine for his specific scenario and your suggestions may be overkill.

Comment: @RyanDansie even if we took scalability out of the equation, the approach is still flawed. Using static variables in a multi-threaded environment such as ASP.NET will more than likely result in unexpected (and difficult to trace) bugs.

Comment: My intention is create Dictionary with Tokens and Expiring dates. Also I'am going to create some windows service application. This application will call web api controller every 5min to remove expired tokens from dictionary. Is something wrong with that?

Comment: @Shagohad yes, ASP.NET is *multi-threaded* but dictionaries are not thread-safe so at a minimum you should use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). Given your particular use of it I guess having it as a `static` variable is viable, however, just bare in mind this ain't going to scale beyond a single machine & as your list grows, so will your servers memory consumption, not to mention if your site goes down you lose all your tokens....So many reasons why, if this is a serious API, you should really be looking at tools like memcached or Redis.

Comment: @James after Your post i decided to stop using my first idea. Now i decided to store all information insisde in Token, such as expiring date and login. Also, this Token is encrypted by AesCryptoServiceProvider, using Key and SymmetricAlgorith.IV. After that, token is converted into ToBase64String. I hope so that is better idea.

Comment: @Shagohad encrypting the token, albeit safer, will make no difference (unless you now store/access them differently as well?).

Comment: @James Why there will be no difference?. And what You mean "storing/accessing them differently" ?

Comment: Encrypting the token isn't going to make any difference to how you are managing the tokens (which is where the issues are).

Comment: But now I'am not going to store this token anywhere. I'am not going to use dictionary anymore.